# How do I group low relative abundance microbial genera as "Other" on my relative abundance graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, phyloseq

This is the code for how I have been separating out the top 10 orders in the data set to graph relative abundance. How could I include the top 10 orders + **an 11th group called others** with the remaining data to have my stacked bars fill up to 100%?

`order.sum = tapply(taxa_sums(relabun), tax_table(relabun)[, "Order"], sum, na.rm=TRUE)`
`top10orders = names(sort(order.sum, TRUE))[1:10]`
`ps2 = prune_taxa((tax_table(relabun)[, "Order"] %in% top10orders), relabun)`
`ps_top10orders <- tax_glom(ps2,taxrank = "Order")`
`ps_top10orders<-transform_sample_counts(ps_top10orders,function(x) x / sum(x))`
`ps_top10orders<-psmelt(ps_top10orders)`
`ps_top10orders<-arrange(ps_top10orders,Order)`

Comment: Have you considered `forcats::fct_lump_n()` or `forcats::fct_lump_prop()`?

Comment: Yes, so I can view the tables with that, how do I use it to prune my data into a top 10 + others? 
What would the line of code look like? It would have to come after I take relabun?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your data, so I can't advice you on that. Generally speaking, the quality of answers you get on SO depend on how well people can reproduce the problem you are having. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for how to ask questions people can help you with.